# Appending the only element in a list to a new list

Tags: python, list, indexing

2. Write a Python function sort_a_list(s) that takes a list of numbers or single characters 's' and returns a sorted list.

a. You cannot use the python function sort(), but you can use min() and/or max()

b. If the input parameter contains duplicate values, return a list containing only unique values (note: capital and lower case characters are not the same)

c. Examples:

i. sort_a_list([2,-3]) -> [-3,2]

ii. sort_a_list([2,3,2]) -> [2,3]

iii. sort_a_list([2,3, 1]) -> [1,2,3]

iv. sort_a_list(['z','a']) -> ['a','z']

v. sort_a_list(['H','B']) -> ['B', 'H']

vi. sort_a_list(['a', 'B']) -> ['B','a']

```
    if s == []:
        return []

    number_list = []
    letter_list = []
    final_list = []

    if type(s[0])==int:
        my_list = 'numbers'
    else:
        my_list = 'letters'
        i=0
        while i < len(s):
            #convert letters to ascii
            s[i]=ord(s[i])
            i+=1
    if my_list == 'numbers':

        i = 0
        while 0 != len(s):
            #sort the list
            number_list.append(min(s))
            s.remove(min(s))
            i+=1

            j=0
            while j < len(number_list)-1:
                #remove duplicates
                if number_list[j]==number_list[j+1]:
                    number_list.remove(number_list[j+1])
                j+=1
        return number_list

    else:
        #sorts through the letters
        i = 0
        while 0 < len(s):
            #sort the list by ascii value
            letter_list.append(min(s))
            s.remove(min(s))
            #take out the minimum value to get the second lowest etc.
            i+=1

            j=0
            while j < len(letter_list)-1:
                #remove duplicates
                if letter_list[j]==letter_list[j+1]:
                    letter_list.remove(letter_list[j+1])
                j+=1

                while 0<len(letter_list):
                    final_list.append(chr(letter_list[0]))
                    letter_list.remove(letter_list[0])

                    while len(letter_list)!=0:
                        final_list.append(letter_list[0])
                        letter_list.pop()
                        final_list[-1]=chr(final_list[-1])

    return final_list,letter_list[0],len(letter_list)

print(sort_a_list(['a','B','d','K','e']))
```

I'm getting an output of (['B', 'K', 'a', 'd'], 101, 1)

How can I take the 101 from letter_list, convert it from ASCII to a character and append it to final_list? I keep getting type errors and index errors after trying a bunch of different ways.

Comment: you don't need to change the strings to integers, you can compare strings directly

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I didn't realise until I tested that list with .sort outside of the function. I guess Python automatically sorts by ascii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out how to do it, never mind!

```
def sort_a_list(s):
    if s == []:
        return []

    number_list = []
    letter_list = []
    final_list = []

    if type(s[0])==int:
        my_list = 'numbers'
    else:
        my_list = 'letters'

    if my_list == 'numbers':

        i = 0
        while 0 != len(s):
            #sort the list
            number_list.append(min(s))
            s.remove(min(s))
            i+=1

            j=0
            while j < len(number_list)-1:
                #remove duplicates
                if number_list[j]==number_list[j+1]:
                    number_list.remove(number_list[j+1])
                j+=1
        return number_list

    else:
        #sorts through the letters
        i = 0
        while 0 < len(s):
            letter_list.append(min(s))
            s.remove(min(s))
            #take out the minimum value to get the second lowest etc.
            i+=1

            j=0
            while j < len(letter_list)-1:
                #remove duplicates
                if letter_list[j]==letter_list[j+1]:
                    letter_list.remove(letter_list[j+1])
                j+=1

    return letter_list

print(sort_a_list(['a','B','d','K','e','e','B']))
```

Comment: notice how your code for sorting ints and chars is exactly the same. You don't need to make that distinction!

Comment: I wrote the int part on Wednesday and the char part Sunday so I forgot about it.